# excel vba macro stopped by select sheet worksheet not found popup box

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which creates formula links in cells to many different excel files in a saved directory.

All the excel files should have the same worksheet names but sometimes one will slip through where it doesn't.

As a result this select sheet worksheet not found popup box appears and will halt the macro from continuing unless a user clicks ok or cancel.

I have tried `application.displayalerts = false` but it doesn't prevent this. Also tried an autoIT script but even this popup box seems to halt the script until a user clicks the mouse somewhere.

Is there a way to stop this pop up box from appearing?

[excel popup box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjdvS.png)

Comment: You say all the excel files should have the same worksheet names. Maybe you can add some validation to an existing loop (For Each/Next, or maybe Do While/Loop) so that if a ws name is not pre-defined ,your code can either ignore it or rename it or something. Something like: "If ws Is Name1 or Name2 or etc.. Then (do something)" or you could use "If Not ws Is Name1 or Name2 or etc Then (do something or exit to go to next)" etc...

Comment: Try to research `on error resume next` and `on error goto 0`, but if not used carefully some critical errors can be skipped.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide the code you use or add a [mcve]. Otherwise we need to guess what you are doing. Reading [ask] might help to improve your question too.

Comment: thanks I ended up using the application.exceute4macro function to test whether the sheet exists.